# ESLint: Warning in resolving Meteor pseudo-globals

Tags: meteor, eslint

ESLint is giving a warning for:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
```

The warning is: Unable to resolve path to module 'meteor/meteor'. How I can turn it off? Or resolve it?

Comment: Meteor is a framework built on top of nodejs. Meteor built it's own packaging system. I don't know how it gets resolved. Meteor/Meteor is looking for Meteor within Meteor package system. Meteor/underscore is looking for underscore within Meteor package system. Meteor has a package manager called atmospherejs. Some of these will be removed in upcoming versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been using [eslint-import-resolver-meteor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-meteor)

```
settings: {
    'import/resolver': 'meteor'
},
```

Comment: Thanks, I have marked this answer as answered. Though the solution suggested by @saimeunt is correct and works, this is the right solution to the problem.

Comment: which file did you add this?

Answer (score 10):

You need to add a Meteor related special rule to your `.eslintrc.json` :

```
{
  "rules": {
    "import/no-unresolved": ["error", { "ignore": ["^meteor/", "^/"] }]
  }
}
```

This rule will add 2 exceptions to the `import/no-unresolved` :

- `meteor/` to allow importing Meteor packages from the `meteor/` pseudo directory.
- `/` to allow importing packages from the root of your Meteor project (eg. `/imports/collections/Posts`).

Answer (score 0):

My settings are as below:

```
"settings": {
    "import/resolver": "meteor",
    "import/core-modules": [ "meteor/meteor" ],
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": "off"
},
```